# Oracle (SQL Developer): How to convert TIMESTAMP string includeing UTC Offset

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper, utc

## Objective

Identify the correct TIMESTAMP format and the cause of the issue.

### Problem

Tring to load a CSV which includes timestamp including UTC offset.

```
2014-01-01T00:38:51.000+11:00
```

The format string is below.

```
YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM
```

However, getting an error message.

> Invalid format YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM  is specified.

### SQL Developer

**TIMESTAMP**

[image]

**TIMESTAMP with TZ**
[image]

Please suggest how to fix this and the reason.

### References

[Oracle 9: Convert date from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format to iso8601 formatted datetime [closed]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107403/oracle-9-convert-date-from-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-format-to-iso8601-formatted-date)

Comment: The data type you want is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`, not `TIMESTAMP`. Best of luck.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis, thanks for the comment. However it still gave the same error.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the timestamp with timezone format:

```
SQL> select to_timestamp_tz('2014-01-01T00:38:51.000+11:00',
  2       'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') as result from dual;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-JAN-14 12.38.51.000000000 AM +11:00

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

(What is DISPLAYED is in a different format - it uses my NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT session parameter - but the conversion from string to timestamp with timezone worked perfectly fine.)

Definitely a SQL Developer issue - you will need to find out how this is done in their interface.